# Critical angle equations - air and not air

Tags: optics, refraction

When the first medium is air, then $\sin(c) = 1/n$ where $c$ is the critical angle and $n$ is the refractive index of $n_2/n_1$ (where $n_2$ is second medium and $n_1$ is in air). So, $1/(n_2/n_1)$ would be $n_1/n_2$.

However, when calculating with the first medium being not air, I find that you calculate $\sin c$ by $\sin(c)= n_2/n_1$. This is the complete reciprocal!

Answer (score 1):

It should be just a problem of definitions of the mediums and their refractive indices. In the general case, when you have two mediums separated by a boundary and with refractive indices $n_1$ and $n_2$, the sine of the critical angle is equal to the ratio between the smaller index and the greater, i.e
$$
\sin c  = 
\begin{cases}
n_1/n_2 ~ \quad \textrm{if}~n_1<n_2 \\
n_2/n_1 ~ \quad \textrm{if}~n_2<n_1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
This is because the critical angle exists only if light passes from the medium with greater refractive index to the other with smaller value, and not *viceversa*. In that case, there exists an incidence angle $c$ for which the refraction angle of the light turns out to be $\pi/2$ (actually this is the operative definition of the critical angle). From this value and above there will be *total internal reflection*, i.e. no light passes to the other medium.

At this point I think that your doubt is just a matter of definitions in the different problems you encountered. Maybe in a problem in which air is one of the two mediums, the author prefers to say that $n_1$ is the index of the air and $n_2>n_1$ the other (usually the air is the medium with smaller refractive index in the problems). Conversely, when there is no air, I would say that usually $n_1$ and $n_2$ are respectively just the first and the second medium in which the light passes, with $n_1>n_2$ to allow the possibility of a total internal reflection.